# Upload my output to my aws webserver

Tags: linux, cron, curl, jq, api

I want to use the output data from my cmd to the Dashboard in a webserver in a table format.

I ran this command:

```
curl -s "http://3.135.18.96:8153/go/api/support" | jq '."Config Statistics"."Valid Config"."Number of agents"'
```

I got the output as 1 and now how can I use this output to reflect it on the server also want a auto update of this API.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean "_how can I use this output to reflect it on the server_"? What do you mean by "_want an auto update of this API_"? Please [edit] your question to be more precise. You may want to include an example or two to help explain the issue better.

Comment: not sure how to frame this, 
I have called an api and got output of that, say as "2". Now, I want this output to be updated in my server hosted in my aws environment. 
Ex - curl -s "http://3.135.18.96:8153/go/api/support" | jq '."Config Statistics"."Valid Config" ' 
with this cmd I got the output, now have to upload it to server. Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: When you say `cmd` do you mean the Microsoft's Windows program `cmd` or did you mean something else?

Comment: You are not clear: You were asked to update the question. Also avoid abrivs. Give examples. What is 1 and 2?

Comment: Is your question: I have just used curl, to get a file to my local Gnu/Linux machine. I now want it on my AWS machine. How do I get it to there?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes , that's the question.
 curl -s "http://3.135.18.96:8153/go/api/support"                                                                                                  | jq '."Config Statistics"."Valid Config"."Number of schedulable materials"'| t                                                                                                 ee t1.txt
O/p - 2
I'm using linux, I used this curl on my Go server to collect data about my materials scheduled, Hence I got the result as 2. Now I want this to be published in a tomcat server. No idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Please put all clarification in the question. Please read **all** of our comments, and address them, by editing the question.